# Search key in big text and get part of text with key php

Tags: php

I have a big text and key:

```
$text = 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority 
have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't 
look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to 
be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum 
generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first 
true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a 
handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. 
The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, 
or non-characteristic words etc.';

$key = 'therefore always';

$getBoldKeyWithText = str_replace($key, '<span class="font-bold">'.$key.'</span>', $text); //get key with bold text
```

I need get this result:

The generated Lorem Ipsum is **therefore always** free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.

Now I get the full text. I want to get the first sentence in the text with the key found.

```
echo $getBoldKeyWithText;
```

Comment: So what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: @Nick now I get all text. I need get only part of text with searched key.

Comment: please clarify your questrion and highlight what your code does/does not do correctly

Comment: What defines "part of text"?

Comment: @Nick I need get this: `The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.`

Comment: @Dronax but if the key was, say, 'repeat predefined` how would you decide what the expected output was?

Comment: @Nick I don't know. I updated my question :)

Comment: You still haven't defined what you mean by 'part of the text'. If you can't tell us what the expected output should be for *any* given input, how can we possibly answer the question?

Comment: @Nick I want to get the first sentence in the text with the key found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace) to extract the sentence containing the key phrase and at the same time, enclose it in the `<span>` tag:

```
$key = 'therefore always';
$getBoldKeyWithText = preg_replace('/^.*?([^.]+)(' . preg_quote($key) . ')([^.]+\.).*$/', 
                                   '$1<span class="font-bold">$2</span>$3', $text);
echo $getBoldKeyWithText;
```

Output

```
The generated Lorem Ipsum is <span class="font-bold">therefore always</span> free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MkRYY)